# JSON values to get with .map using in React.Js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, object

I am getting this JSON from the backend with Loopback/Node.Js

```
[
  {
    "label": "Pub Radio",
    "icone": "",
    "Mp3": {
      "33278": {
        "id": 33278,
        "titre": "Ricardo Villalobos - Caminando",
        "intention1": "Doux",
        "intention2": "Doux",
        "intention3": "Doux",
        "langue": "Allemand",
        "visibilite": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "Pub Cd/Dvd",
    "icone": "",
    "Mp3": {
      "33277": {
        "id": 33277,
        "titre": "Mano lo taugh - Primative People",
        "intention1": "Chaleureux, rassurant",
        "intention2": "Joyeux",
        "intention3": "Souriant",
        "langue": "Allemand",
        "visibilite": 1
      },
      "33279": {
        "id": 33279,
        "titre": "Foals - Late Night (Solomun Remix).mp3",
        "intention1": "Amical, complice",
        "intention2": "Amical, complice",
        "intention3": "Amical, complice",
        "langue": "Allemand",
        "visibilite": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "Billboard",
    "icone": "",
    "Mp3": {
      "33280": {
        "id": 33280,
        "titre": "Techno",
        "intention1": "Posé, calme",
        "intention2": "Amical, complice",
        "intention3": "Souriant",
        "langue": "Americain",
        "visibilite": 1
      }
    }
  }
]
```

This is the result after doing a `console.log` in the view where I want to display the results : same as the backend an array of objects and in these objects you can find also multiple objects.

**JSON3:**

[image]

What I wanted to do is to map and show labels and all attributes inside MP3 and all I am getting is extraitMP3.map is not a function. I think that the problem comes from that .map can be used only with arrays but I don't know how to deal with this. Any help would be appreciated

This is the code I built so far :

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {Col, Row,Card,Button} from "antd";
import Emoji from 'a11y-react-emoji';

import ExtraitsCell from "./ExtraitsCell/index";
import extraitMP3 from "./data";
import {arrayMove, SortableContainer} from "react-sortable-hoc";

import ContainerHeader from "components/ContainerHeader/index";
import IntlMessages from "util/IntlMessages";
import {getExtraitMp3} from "appRedux/actions/Comedien";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {userSignOut} from "appRedux/actions/Auth";
//import axios from "axios";

var moment = require('moment');
 const ExtraitsMp3 = SortableContainer(({extraitMP3}) => {
  return ( 
    <Row>   
      <Col span={24}>
        {extraitMP3.map((extraitMP32, index) => (
          <ExtraitsCell key={index} index={index} extraitMP32={extraitMP32}/>
        ))}
      </Col>
    </Row>
  );
}); 

class ListExtrait extends Component {
  onSortEnd = ({oldIndex, newIndex}) => {
    this.setState({
      extraitMP3: arrayMove(this.state.extraitMP3, oldIndex, newIndex),
    });
  };

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      extraitMP3:extraitMP3, 
     }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const user = localStorage.user;
    var DateActuelle = new Date().toISOString(); // get current date
    const TokenDateCreation = user ? JSON.parse(user).created : '';
    const TokenExpirationSeconds = user ? JSON.parse(user).ttl : '';
    var dateFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss';
    var TokenExpirationDate = moment(TokenDateCreation).add('seconds', TokenExpirationSeconds).format(dateFormat);
    var ActualDate = moment(DateActuelle).format(dateFormat);
    //console.log('localStorage :',localStorage.user)
    if (ActualDate < TokenExpirationDate)
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.props.userSignOut(); //passing the user id
      }, 86300000)
      this.props.getExtraitMp3();
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
     //console.log('nextProps : ', nextProps)
     if (nextProps.extraitMP3 !== prevState.extraitMP3 && nextProps.extraitMP3) {
       return { extraitMP3: nextProps.extraitMP3 };   
     }
     else return null;
   }


  render() {
    const {extraitMP3/*,label */} = this.state;
    console.log('Extrait MP3 ',extraitMP3) 
    console.log('******************');

    return (
    <Card>   
      <Card styleName="gx-card-list icon icon-data-display gx-mr-2 gx-text-blue gx-fs-xl"> 
        <div className="gx-media-body">
        <IntlMessages id="menu.MesExtraisMP3.PubTV"/> &nbsp; <i className={`icon icon-data-display gx-mr-2 gx-text-blue`}/>
        </div>
        <div className="gx-main-content gx-mb-4">
          <ContainerHeader  match={this.props.match}/>
           <ExtraitsMp3 extraitMP3={extraitMP3} onSortEnd={this.onSortEnd} useDragHandle={true} /> 
        </div>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" labelCol={{xs: 24, sm: 5}} wrapperCol={{xs: 24, sm: 12}}>
              Enregistrer
        </Button>
      </Card>  

      <Card styleName="gx-card-list icon icon-data-display gx-mr-2 gx-text-blue"> 
        <div className="gx-media-body">
        <IntlMessages id="menu.MesExtraisMP3.JeuVideo"/> &nbsp; 
        <Emoji symbol="ðŸŽ®" label="jeu" className={`gx-fs-xl`}/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </div>
        <div className="gx-main-content gx-mb-4">
          <ContainerHeader  match={this.props.match}/>
          <ExtraitsMp3 extraitMP3={extraitMP3} onSortEnd={this.onSortEnd} useDragHandle={true}/>
        </div>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" labelCol={{xs: 24, sm: 5}} wrapperCol={{xs: 24, sm: 12}}>
              Enregistrer
        </Button>
      </Card>  
    </Card> 

    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ comedien }) => {
  const { extraitMP3} = comedien;
  return { extraitMP3}
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { userSignOut ,
  getExtraitMp3
})(ListExtrait);
```

the ./data contains this :

```
export default [{
  'label':'',
  'icone':'',
  'Mp3':{
  'idSon':{
  'titre': '',
  'visibilite': '',
  'langage': '',
  'intention1': '',
  'intention2': '',
  'intention3': '',
   } },}]
```

Comment: To clarify, you used `console.log` on `extraitMP3` inside your `ExtraitsMp3` component, correct?

Comment: yes exactly i did that

Comment: Hmmm. What is the type of `extraitMP3`? With some types, you can use `Array.from` to convert it to an array.

Comment: Wouldn't a stackblitz example have made this easier? Especially since your json is an image rather than text

Comment: i am not used to stackblitz sorry but ichanged the images above to text. extratiMP3 is an array of objects as shown and in this objects you can find several objects each one is identified by its id